# Build D3js Area Chart with negative values

Tags: d3.js

We have an example for bar chart with negative values...[Bar Chart with negative values](http://bl.ocks.org/2368837)

Is there any similar example for area chart?

Answer (score 10):

This is an old question but I thought I may be able to shed some light for anyone else that lands here. When setting up your svg area simply set y0 to your charts 0 line position. For example:

```
d3.svg.area()
  .x(function(d) {
    return x(d.x);
  })
 .y0(function() {
   return y(0);
 })
 .y1(function(d) {
   return y(d.y);
 });
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to fill the negative area with another color?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, I've created a fiddle based off Mike Bostock's post on [reusable charts](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/): http://jsfiddle.net/C5gYv/

Essentially what I do is check if the data is positive or negative and then set y0 and y1 respectively:

```
    area = d3.svg.area()
        .x(X)

    ...

        g.select(".area").attr("d",
            area.y1(function (d) {
                // the highest point
                if (d[1] <= 0) {
                    return yScale(0);
                } else {
                    return Y(d);
                }
            })
                .y0(function (d) {
                // the lowest point
                if (d[1] <= 0) {
                    return Y(d);
                } else {
                    return yScale(0);
                }
            }));
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I'd be interested to see a nicer solution though. This seemed overkill when I wrote it.

Comment: Big big thanks for your help, Hardbyte! Your piece of code you posted here helped save a couple of hours of sleep for me tonight before a last minute demo. And thanks to Santa_612 for asking a question. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the JSFiddle of @Hardbyte because I think it was not proper.

Here is the updated fiddle [new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sachin4dotnet/C5gYv/31/).

What I have changed is -

```
// Update the area path.
        if (showArea) {
            g.select(".area").attr("d",
            area.y1(function (d) {
                // the highest point
                return Y(d);
            })
            .y0(function (d) {
                // the lowest point
                return yScale(0);
            }));
        }
```